# Can we write two or more elements style in single line in JQuery

Tags: css, jquery

Write two or more elements style in single line in JQuery, where id of element created concatinating text by json object.value

```
     checkSucess = function(first,last,value) {
        // Jquery ajax with url,params and response
        doPost('sucess.php',
                     'first=' + first +
                    '&last=' + last,
                    function(response) {
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                            $('#button'+obj.a,'#button'+obj.b,'#button'+obj.c).css({'text-decoration':'blink','color':'#4ECFBD'});
                    }
        );
     }
```

Here

```
    $('#button'+obj.a).css({'text-decoration':'blink','color':'Magenta','font-weight':'bold'});
    $('#button'+obj.b).css({'text-decoration':'blink','color':'Magenta','font-weight':'bold'});
    $('#button'+obj.c).css({'text-decoration':'blink','color':'Magenta','font-weight':'bold'});
```

works correct ,

but

```
   $('#button'+obj.a,'#button'+obj.b,'#button'+obj.c).css({'text-decoration':'blink','color':'#4ECFBD'});
```

not works why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to merge the selectors in a string, in this way:

```
  $('#button'+obj.a + ', #button'+obj.b + ', #button'+obj.c).css({'text-decoration':'blink','color':'#4ECFBD'});
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to merge selectors:

```
  $('#button'+obj.a)
    .add('#button'+obj.b)
    .add('#button'+obj.c)
    .css({'text-decoration':'blink','color':'#4ECFBD'});
```

Comment: @Jusnit The first one, unless you find code readability extremely important.

Comment: $('#button'+obj.a + ', #button'+obj.b + ', #button'+obj.c).css({'text-decoration':'blink','color':'#4ECFBD'});   This is your suggestion Isn't?   Is this Jquery code is more faster(execution) than other one?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the comma wrong. This is possible, but it needs to be written like

```
$('#button'+obj.a+',#button'+obj.b+',#button'+obj.c).css({ ... });
```

Notice that now the commas are *inside* the string.

**Update:** I was going to add that it might be more readable to write this as

```
$('#button'+obj.a)
.add('#button'+obj.b) 
.add('#button'+obj.c) 
.css({ ... });
```

but Rob W beat me to it. :-)

Comment: @jfriend00: I 'm not saying that you are wrong, but IMHO there's no point really in trying to guess how such an inconsequential operation might be optimized.